# FindByTags with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I grab this kind of array.

This is a **var_dump** of my **$tags** variable.

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "4" }
```

**My entity**

```
<?php
namespace Lan\CrmBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Link
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lan\SecurityBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="links")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\LinkTag", inversedBy="links")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="LinkTagToLink",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="link_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="link_tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
     * )
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return Link
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Link
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set created_at
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Link
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->created_at = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created_at
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Lan\SecurityBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Link
     */
    public function setUser(\Lan\SecurityBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Lan\SecurityBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add tags
     *
     * @param \Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\LinkTag $tags
     * @return Link
     */
    public function addTag(\Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\LinkTag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags[] = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tags
     *
     * @param \Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\LinkTag $tags
     */
    public function removeTag(\Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\LinkTag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Get tags
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}
```

**My entire controller**:

```
namespace Lan\CrmBundle\Controller;

use Lan\CrmBundle\Entity\Link;
use Lan\CrmBundle\Form\LinkType;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class LinkController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tags = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:LinkTag')->findAll();

        if($request->query->has('tags')) {
            $tags = $request->query->get('tags');
            //var_dump($tags); die();
            $links = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Link')->findByTags($tags);
            var_dump($links); die();
        } else {
            $links = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Link')->findBy(
                array(),
                array('id' => 'desc')
            );
        }

        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $links,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),
            4
        );

        return $this->render('LanCrmBundle:Link:index.html.twig', compact('pagination', 'tags'));
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns in ...

I think I can't use **->findByTags()** like I want...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post the entity class here

Comment: I've edited my first post, as you can imagine I grab my tags from GET parameters from a multiple select with **tags[]** as name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can findByTags because SF2 won't know if you want `AND` or `OR` for tags.

The only solution I can suggest you is that you need to query from link_tag table (use repository `LanCrmBundle:LinkTag`) manually to get all `link.id` then continue to retrieve link data using `LanCrmBundle:Link`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way but not really what I want :

```
public function findByUsersAndTags($users, $tags)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->leftJoin('l.tags', 't')->addSelect('t')
        ->leftJoin('l.user', 'u')->addSelect('u')
        ->orderBy('l.id', 'desc');

    if($users) {
        foreach($users as $user_id) {
            $queryBuilder->orHaving('u.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $user_id);
        }
    }

    if($tags) {
        foreach($tags as $tag_id) {
            $queryBuilder->orHaving('t.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $tag_id);
        }
    }

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```